# mouse up javascript event not firing over image control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, image

I have an asp.net image control and am trying to simulate a drag event over it(I don't want the image to move). I just need the co-ordinates of the initial and final position. the mousedown event gets fired but the mouse up event doesn't get fired. Could you help me out ??

```
var t;

    function set_coordinates_up(event) {
        pos_x = event.offsetX ? (event.offsetX) : event.pageX - document.getElementById("divScreenshot").offsetLeft;
        pos_y = event.offsetY ? (event.offsetY) : event.pageY - document.getElementById("divScreenshot").offsetTop;
        var hdf = document.getElementById('HiddenField1')
        if (hdf != null) hdf.value = t + " " + pos_x + " " + pos_y

    }
    function set_coordinates_down(event) {

        pos_x = event.offsetX ? (event.offsetX) : event.pageX - document.getElementById("divScreenshot").offsetLeft;
        pos_y = event.offsetY ? (event.offsetY) : event.pageY - document.getElementById("divScreenshot").offsetTop;
        t = "4" + " " + pos_x + " " + pos_y

    }
<div id="divScreenshot" onclick="set_coordinates(event)" onmousedown="set_coordinates_down(event) " onmouseup="set_coordinates_up(event) " >
                <asp:Image ID="imgScreenshot" runat="server"  />
            </div>
```

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried.

Comment: Are you aware that the mouseup event only gets fired if the mouse is still over the image? If the mouse is released outside, you won't get the event and you need to get it from the whole page.

Comment: yes I am releasing it above the image.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using jQuery UI? There might be a little bit of a learning curve but they already did the Draggable plugin to make pretty much any object draggable. Its nice to do it yourself, but why reinvent the wheel?

[JQuery UI - Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)

Comment: I dont want to move the image. I want the image to remain in the same place. So I click on the image, move the mouse over the image and then release it over the image. But for some reason the mouse up event is not firing.

Answer (score -1):

Try binding the events on the image rather than the container div.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. Do you have any helpful links ?

Comment: It's similar to how you binded them to your div element! <img src="..." alt="..." onclick="some()" />
In other words defining onclick and other attributes is known as binding events. So instead of binding them to the <div>, bind them to the <img> that you are loading using asp. I dont know how to do it using asp.

Comment: An asp image doesn't have those events by default. I got an alternative solution by using an asp:Image button. But I still don't get why the above doesn't work.

Comment: hmm. try editing ur code to : 
<div id="divScreenshot" onclick="alert('clicked');" onmousedown="alert('mouse down');" onmouseup="alert('mouseup');" >
                <asp:Image ID="imgScreenshot" runat="server"  />
            </div>

and then check if the proper alerts are fired. That will tell u of any error in ur javascript fns. They may be preventing next ones to fire. Or use google chrome's developer tools, they help a lot in these cases.